# Unable to call a function with a Codable Generic Parameter

Tags: swift, generics

I have a class that takes a generic parameter T `class CacheRepository<T> {}`that contains a `func transform()`. In which I need to call another function with the following signature `func transformCodable<U: Codable>(ofType: U.Type)`-- if `T` conforms to `Codable` protocol. But I failed to do so. Below are my trials with their compilation errors.

Trial 1:

```
func transform() {
    if T.self is Codable.Type {
        // Error: In argument type 'CacheRepository<T>.T.Type' (aka 'T.Type'), 'T' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'
       sharedStorage!.transformCodable(ofType: T.self)
    }
}
```

Trial 2:

```
func transform() {
    if T.self is Codable.Type {
        //Cannot invoke 'transformCodable' with an argument list of type '(ofType: (Codable))'
        //Expected an argument list of type '(ofType: U.Type)'
        sharedStorage!.transformCodable(ofType: (T as! Codable).self)
    }
}
```

Trial 3: I tried to extend `CacheRepository` class if `T is Codable`, but the extension `transform` function never gets called, when called in the init() function. And if I called it after the instance is created, it doesn't get called in all cases.

```
class CacheRepository<T> {
    func transform() {
      print("non-codable transform")
    }
}

extension CacheRepository where T: Codable {
    func transform() {
     sharedStorage!.transformCodable(ofType: T.self)
    }
}
```

example: This works

```
let transform = CacheRepository<Int>().transform()
```

But if I added a shared instance inside the `CacheRepository` class, and tried to call `transform` after instantiation, it doesn't get called. And the really odd this is, if I called the `tranform` on the new instance in console the right `transform` is called.

Answer (score 0):

How is this?

```
extension CacheRepository where T: Codable {
    func transform() {
        print("Codable")
        sharedStorage!.transformCodable(ofType: T.self)
    }
}
extension CacheRepository {
    func transform() {
        print("Non-codable")
    }
}
```

This worked as expected in a very simplified `CacheRepository`. But not sure if it works in your actual `CacheRepository`, please try.

Comment: Well, if it's called from the init() method, it doesn't work.

Comment: @user2037296, thanks for reporting. You should better clarify from where the method is called. Static resolution of generic based overloading may be affected by many things.

Comment: you are right, I have edited my question. And added a new trial in which the extension doesn't work, even after instantiation...Would you please take a look, and let me know if you have a justification to this weird behavior.

Comment: @user2037296, it is not being clear enough how the method is called. But I guess you are trying something impossible under the current limitation of Swift generics. Overloading is resolved in compile time. This simple sentence may explain almost all the behavior.